# jQuery scrollTo minified

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I downloaded the latest jquery.scrollTo from the [plugins site](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo). Is there an obvious reason why the minified version does not work? With the exact same code the console throws the error:

`$.scrollTo is not a function`

For info this is my only statement:

`$.scrollTo('-=600px', 400, { axis:'y' });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minified version does work, make sure you're including it correctly, e.g. that your server relative location, permission, etc works...try accessing it directly in your browser.

[You can see a working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/8ueex/) using: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js (**don't hotlink**, this is just a demo showing the minified version works)

Answer (score 0):

Check for the closing ; after each statement. It is optional but the minifization makes it required.